# Virtual terminal vertical scrolling is really slow

Tags: terminal, console, scrolling

I'm using Manjaro Linux, runlevel 3.

The odd thing is, whenever using commands like `less` and `man`, the page scrolling is really slow. Whether I'm using <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, scrolling with the arrows or using any hotkey bound to that action.

Is there a way to speed up screen movement?

I'm not using any GUI, so mouse emulation is out the window.

Comment: Use a faster terminal emulator, e.g. rxvt. http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html

Comment: Could I use lsmod or something similar to see which emulator I currently have installed?

Comment: `xprop`, then click inside the window

Comment: I'm not using any GUI, so mouse emulation is out the window. I get the error message, "unable to open display."

Comment: Ohh... Then don't use fb (framebuffer) for console. fb is always f*cking slow. Use pure VGA textmode, which is fast like hell.

Comment: @IporSircer Whether text mode is fast or slow depends on the graphics card. If you want speed, use X with bitmap fonts.

Comment: Why would anything other than text mode be loaded if I'm defaulting to run-level 3? Isn't that run-level text-only by default?